# Nuspec file renaming is not working with octopack

Tags: deployment, msbuild, teamcity, octopus-deploy

I am auto publishing using octopus and teamcity. I have a project with multiple configurations and need to have different package id's for same solution. Also have 1 nuspec file in the project. In teamcity project configuration also passing the /p:OctopusNuSpecFileName=team.IUS.nuspec to msbuild. But still it is not changing the name of that package to the one I am passing in build parameter. I want team package to be renamed as team.IUS. Artefact that it creates is still creating team.1.0.0.19.nupkg.
Any Idea what I am doing wrong. Please guide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 nuspec = 1 project. if you want mulitple packages for a project you should create a nuspec for each one and use a post build event to name and place the different packages in different lib folders.